# My iPhone application project is taking more than 90% of battery usage

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created a project which consists of coredata core location there is a lot of stuff doing with coredata my project is in final stage now I installed the application in my iPhone the battery usage is taking more than 90% is that a problem apple accepts it or not

Answer (score 0):

This is really a critical issue if you app taking more than 80% of battery. After iOS 8.0 the OS will automatically kill your app if it will take such huge amount of device battery. So I don't think Apple will reject but this is not a good situation for any app user.

Comment: Okay I understand if Apple will not reject then no problem and app is working very fine and I put like background refresh location and background refresh fetch data that makes any reason

Comment: Still I will suggest you read the apple guideline before submitting. Recently I have also worked on same type of application which took around 70-80% of battery consumption.

Comment: I don't understand one thing my app size not more than 1mb and it consists coredata location like this

Comment: I think coredata location is updating location every second.

Comment: It's depend upon your location accuracy setting within the app.